# How to send a multipart request with php

Tags: php, html, multipartform-data

I'd like to know how I can send a multipart/form-data encoded post request out of php. I already found this code here:

```
$destination = "http://yourdomain.com/yoururl";



$eol = "\r\n";

$data = '';


$mime_boundary=md5(time());


$data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;

$data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="somedata"' . $eol . $eol;

$data .= "Some Data" . $eol;

$data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;

$data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="somefile"; 
filename="filename.ext"' . $eol;

$data .= 'Content-Type: text/plain' . $eol;

$data .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $eol . $eol;

$data .= chunk_split(base64_encode("Some file content")) . $eol;

$data .= "--" . $mime_boundary . "--" . $eol . $eol; // finish with two 
eol's!!


$params = array('http' => array(

                  'method' => 'POST',

                  'header' => 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' 
. $mime_boundary . $eol,

                  'content' => $data


               ));


$ctx = stream_context_create($params);

$response = @file_get_contents($destination, FILE_TEXT, $ctx);
```

(http://vedovini.net/2009/08/posting-multipart-form-data-using-php/)
My question is: How can I define the file that should be sent?
(Just to explain what I like to do: The User uploads a file with a simple http form, the php script receives it and should "resend" the file to another url). I also have to send 1 variable in a json array along with the file.

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding the file data, I'd remove that part. Also I'd have used curl instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cURL instead of file_get_contents, there is a similar question about using it with multipart POST submissions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl).

Comment: Thanks,helped. The problem is that the api I have to send the file to doesn't accept filenames... So i Have to rename the file itself I think... I also tried something like this here:  [link](http://hastebin.com/opuniyiboz.bash) But that didn't work either. So is there a way to fix my code or is there a way to rename the $fildedata object directly ? (Code is based on the code of the other thread.