# Execute a specific HTTP POST using php

Tags: php, forms, http, curl, post

I want to execute a specific HTTP post using php (Yes this is different to other threads).
So, a url named *http://127.0.0.1:8060/PFOOptions/?PFOID=0x000000950C420940* has a form post that I want to execute using php.
It looks like this:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and the submit button looks like this.

```
<input type="submit" name="Okay" value="Okay">
```

The form is filled with various inputs such as *RemoteAdress* and *LocalPort*. I tried this code to execute the post, but how can the code know which specific form I want to execute? And that the submit has name="Okay". Where do I put that information?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8060/PFOOptions/?PFOID=0x0000004C98FFBDD0';
$data = array('LocalPort' => '2743', 'RemoteAdress' => 'halo.com');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
?>
```

What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

> how can the code know which specific form I want to execute?

In general: It can't.

The HTML form combined with the user input to that form tells the browser how to construct an HTTP request.

When you write PHP to make an HTTP request, then you need to write PHP which takes the place of the form and the user input.

---

> And that the submit has name="Okay". Where do I put that information?

Submit buttons (if used to submit the form) add their name and value to the submitted form data just like any other form control.

So you put it in the same place at the rest of the form data.

i.e. the array you assign to `$data`

---

> What am I missing out on?

You are constructing data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

You have also specified that the Content-Type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

It is good that these match, however, the form says `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so it is possible that the URL you are submitting it to doesn't support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` input and you will need to [change the format of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797740/how-to-send-a-multipart-request-with-php).

---

There may also be other facts that we can't determine from the information you've provided, such as the expectation of a cookie for authentication purposes.

Comment: Thanks alot for this. But if I want to specify the submit button, like name="Okay", what should I set the value to? So it knows that it is that I want to execute. And also, do you know what I should replace this **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** with?

Comment: @Karldrakar — The value of the submit button. See the linked question - remember you need to encode your data as multipart not just change the content-type to claim it is multipart.