# PHP cURL doesn't set content-length properly

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file via cURL but something is missing. I forces this request to be HTTP 1.0 because cURL adds the Expect: 100 header if I use HTTP 1.1 so thats why the extra header. Here is a simple test code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
  $data = array("id" => $_POST["id"]);
  $data["file"] = "@".realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer 0e39ffba-66cd-4933-9e94-fcdf600c2453',
    'Connection: keep-alive'
  ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/test-api/upload");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 1);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  var_dump($response);
  exit;
}
?>
```

My Jersey based server picks it up, and I can see these headers:

```
INFO: 25 * Server has received a request on thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
25 > POST http://localhost:8080/test-api/upload
25 > authorization: Bearer 0e39ffba-66cd-4933-9e94-fcdf600c2453
25 > connection: keep-alive
25 > content-length: 261
25 > content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------53f7ba34739b4d9e
25 > host: localhost:8080
```

See the content-length? It's way too short. When I send the same file and the same request via my Postman REST client, I get these headers:

```
INFO: 26 * Server has received a request on thread http-nio-8080-exec-3
26 > POST http://localhost:8080/test-api/upload
26 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
26 > accept-language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
26 > authorization: Bearer 0e39ffba-66cd-4933-9e94-fcdf600c2453
26 > cache-control: no-cache, no-cache
26 > connection: keep-alive
26 > content-length: 144954
26 > content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarye5Tg0kEqi10nEBwv
26 > cookie: ff_uvid=126143952; _ga=GA1.1.459454356.1439469592; CAKEPHP=9mffidqo8203ugktan4roc0u82
26 > host: localhost:8080
26 > origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
26 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36
```

The content-length now is set property. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Looks to me like you're just sending the filename, and not the file content.... so that would explain the content length discrepancy

Comment: Well most sources I found says that this is how you need to send files. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The default method for uploading files changed in 5.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using PHP 5.6.0 or later. As of this release, the `@` prefix for file uploads is disabled by default. You can enable it with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

This option was added in 5.5, but the default was `false` for backward compatibility; 5.6 changed the default incompatibly.

The preferred way to perform file uploads starting with 5.5 is with the [CurlFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) class.

```
$data["file"] = new CurlFile(realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually insert the filecontent, this differs from the cli-version of curl.
try:

```
  $data["file"] = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Comment: Please see my comment above

Comment: I don't think this will send it as a file upload, this will send the file contents as raw data.

Comment: What is "file uploading" else than transferring the raw file content? As far as I could see from the question, the file contents should be transmitted in a post-field named "file". In the first place, I tried to explain the difference in content-length

Comment: When you upload a file, additional headers are sent with details about the file, such as its MIME type.

Comment: You do not know, if the asker tries to encapsulate the data this way. As far as I interpreted it, he tried to resemble the @-Operator from the curl-cli-version. This is exactly, what my example does.

Comment: The other difference is how the upload is processed in the receiving script. When you send it this way, the data will be in `$_POST['file']` instead of `$_FILES['file']` (if the target script is written in PHP -- other languages probably have something similar).