# how to send multiple parameters using MultipartUploadRequest

Tags: php, android, file-upload, service, upload

I'm trying to send multiple parameters using `MultipartUploadRequest` (upload service) to PHP and store them in a database. Here's the `MultipartUploadRequest` usage:

```
new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameters to the request
                .addParameter("bossname", bossname)
                .addParameter("field", field)
```

How should I *get* these parameters in PHP? This is the PHP part that does not work:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //checking the required parameters from the request
    if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){

        //connecting to the database
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

        //getting name from the request
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $bossname = $_POST['bossname'];
        $field= $_POST['field'];
```

When I send only `name`, there is no problem—I have the `image` in server and `name` and `url` in my database.
But when I send more parameters like `bossname` or `field`, I get the `image` in my server but nothing is in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting raw image data as multipart/form-data in curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl)

Comment: what do you mean "get parameters in php"? do you mean get the parameters you just set from the MultipartUploadRequest object??

Comment: What is a MultipartUploadRequest? This doesn't look like PHP.

Comment: How to send in java or how to get parameters in php???, you need to make a much clearer question of what is your problem etc.

Comment: Does the data arrive at the server? What happens when you `print_r` or `error_log` the other parameters? If the data is there, you'll need to post the code that insert them into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everybody I find my problem ,I had to write isset for every post

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'] and isset($_POST['bossname']) and isset($_POST['field']))...
```