# How to upload image file from server A to Server B

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I have some idea for upload image file from `www.mysite.com` via FILE input with form To `www.mysite2.com` .
Please let me it possible or not and if possible how I can do it.

Here my sample code.

upload.php in www.mysite2.com

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];       // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "uploads/".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;    // Moving Uploaded file
```

thanks

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl) will help you.

Comment: thanks.but i cant use php script in A side.just only js

Comment: So you want to upload a file to server A and from there upload it to server B, but you can't use PHP on server A? Since it's server A that needs to take the initial upload and pass it on to server B, we need to know what you can use there. (And the question should be tagged with that language instead of PHP).

Comment: ...unless you simply point the action in the upload form directly to server B?

Comment: yea i did tagged php because B side must be php

Answer (score 0):

create form in A side with action of path to B side

HTML from A side

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="www.mysite2.com/upload.php" method="POST">
        <input typ="file" name="file" >
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" >
    </form>
```

and post the file

Comment: great..i did this but file not uploaded with that php script.

Comment: the action will contain the exact path of the page/api route which will upload the image

Comment: if you are using `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']` then from A side change `name="file"` to `name="fileToUpload"` and try again

Comment: anybody can give example for this.

Comment: `<input typ="file" name="file" >` to `<input typ="file" name="fileToUpload" >`

Comment: @SasinduJayampathi If the form posts directly to server B, there's no difference between this and any other file upload. Just google on "file upload with php". There's thousands of tutorials about it, no need for yet another. An check the error log on server B for any potential errors.

Comment: <form id="vltfm" method="POST" action="http://sideb.com/u.php" return false;enctype="multipart/form-data"><input  type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="vitimg" /><input type="submit" /></form>

Comment: @SasinduJayampathi -  I actually think you need `http://` first in your `action`.. `action="http://serverB.com/something.php"`. Otherwise, it will append the action to the current domain.

Comment: `<form id="vltfm" method="POST" action="http://sideb.com/u.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to grab the image file from `server a` to `server b`
just use the following line of code and change the names.

```
<?php 
    $url="http://example.com/image-path/fileName.ext"; //Server a address
    $contents=file_get_contents($url); //Grab the image file
    $save_path="img/fileName.png"; //path where you want to save
    file_put_contents($save_path,$contents);
?>
```

Comment: so how i place $url from file input?

Comment: Since the OP can't use PHP on server A, the file will never exist there. Please read all the comments on the original question.

Comment: @SasinduJayampathi - You don't need to use `<input type="file" />` if you are using these piece of codes. @MagnusEriksson but he said that he's using php on server B so he can do that.