# What is this type of post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, post

hello i found this type of post and would like to use it on curl php

```
-----------------------------265811238319953
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="min_date"

01/01/2017
-----------------------------265811238319953
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="max_date"

12/31/2017
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more details as where this data is coming from?

Comment: That's a `multipart/form-data` request. It's primarily used for uploading binary data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl

Comment: Thank you for your help  Rory McCrossan

Comment: Yep great Thank you all