# How to send Image to Spring API using Symfony 2.8?

Tags: spring, symfony

I have been working in a project that receive an image and returns a list with the most similar that I have in Solr. I have tested the service using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) but I want to make a client using Symfony 2.8 to use the service. I googled a lot and nothing specific found.
My method with Spring should receive a MultipartFile and store it, then another method will process that image...
Here is the code of my uploadFile method. Any help of how to do this with Symfony? Thanks!

Sorry for my English!

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        String extension = storage.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
        if (extension.equals("jpg") || extension.equals("JPG") || extension.equals("jpeg") || extension.equals("png")) {
            storage.store(file);
            storage.copyImage("upload-dir/" + storage.getFile(rootLocation.toFile()));
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
        } else {
            message = "El archivo " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " no es una imagen.";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        message = "Falló la subida";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(message);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand well, you are trying to send a request to your Spring endpoint, when I must achieve this task I usually work with [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart) is a PHP HTTP client that do this this tasks so easy. You can install it with Composer:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0
```

After you can do a HTTP multipart request with this simple code:

```
$client->request('POST', '/post', [
  'multipart' => [
    [
        'name'     => 'file',
        'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
        'filename' => 'image.png'
    ],
  ]
]);
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you. Can I do the same with a lower version of guzzle? Because I only have PHP 5.3 and Composer don't allow me to install that version. Something else: can I get data using POST? I mean, when I send the MultipartFile by POST to the controller on the Service, it is supposed that I have to get a response. How can I do this?

Comment: With your version of PHP it not to easy, for Guzzle you can use the v3 but is to old. You can try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl

Comment: Thank you again for your help, at the end I could use Guzzle. Now, what I can do if I want to send the file posted in the html form? I have been looking on some tutos and all of them just tell me that I have to load it from the source with `'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r')`

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you, are you saying to post the file in a real HTML form?

Comment: I have this:
`<form id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Upload" />
        </form>`
And I want to send to my REST service the file using that form. I am doing something like this but it does not work:
`$file = $_FILES['file'];
  $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost:8091/', [
  'multipart' => [
    [
        'name' => 'file',
        'contents' => fopen('img/b.jpg', 'r')
        //'filename' => 'file'
    ],
  ]
]);
}`

Comment: Do you try to get the form file with $file = $request->files->get('file'); ?