# Uploading a file from PHP to a REST service using curl

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data

How can I send files to a webservice? In order to upload the files, I need to use multipart/form-data; I'm wondering how I can achieve that using curl from PHP.

My code is:

```
$post = [
      "name"=> $_POST["name"],
      "bpm"=> $_POST["bpm"],
      "release"=>$_POST["release"],
      "genre"=> $_POST["genre"],
      "lableId"=> $_POST["lableId"],
      "audio"=>'@'. $_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'].';filename='.$_FILES['audio']['name'].';type='.$_FILES['audio']['type'],
      "image"=>'@'. $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'].';filename='.$_FILES['image']['name'].';type='. $_FILES['image']['type']
];
```

The array `$post` is given to this function:

```
function uploadTrack($url,$post,$token){

  $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


  $data_string = json_encode($post);



  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',$authorization
    /*'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post)*/)
  );

  // execute!
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  // close the connection, release resources used
  curl_close($ch);

  // do anything you want with your response
  return $response;
}
```

The failure I get is:

```
Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

And the failure on the server is:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2869) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It would seem that you try to both send a JSON payload and a form using a multipart upload; this is however not possible and you should take attention on whether the API requests an actual file or a JSON object. Also, if you want to upload a file, using `@` will only work from the command line curl client; if you want to use it from php, refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl

Answer (score 1):

you're doing several things wrong here,

you're sending a json string, but telling the server that it's `multipart/form-data`-encoded, and it appears you're trying to upload files using the @ scheme, which was deprecated in 5.5, stopped working by default in 5.6, and was completely removed in 7.0 - any code running in PHP >= 5.5  should use [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php), not @

in order to upload a file with `multipart/form-data`-encoding, do

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "audio" => new CURLFile($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['type'], $_FILES['image']['name'])
));
```

also get rid of this

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',$authorization
    /*'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post)*/)
  );
```

- curl will automatically set the correct Content-Type and Content-Length headers when using `multipart/form-data` encoding, and unlike you, curl won't make any typos in doing so.