# Error in linkedin media upload api

Tags: php, laravel, linkedin-api

I am trying to upload an image using linkedin api. 
I already uploaded image in my server and now I want to upload the upoaded image url to linkedin. But I got the error

> { "serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"The request is not a multipart
>   request","status":400 }

```
      $curl1 = curl_init();
      $m_url="https://api.linkedin.com/media/upload";

      $curl_header = array("Authorization:Bearer ".$access_token);
      $uploadRequest = array(
            'name'=>'media',
            'filename' => basename($medias[0]),
            'media_data' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($medias[0]))
                );
                curl_setopt_array($curl1, array(
                  CURLOPT_URL => $m_url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$uploadRequest,
                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>$curl_header,

                ));
                $response1 = curl_exec($curl1);
                $err1 = curl_error($curl1);

                curl_close($curl1);
```

This is the request. Please anyone tell me What is the exact issue and how to sort this out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/rich-media-shares#upload)? Specifically, check what headers it states that you need to send.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting raw image data as multipart/form-data in curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl)

Comment: Yeah but it shows about how to upload an image directly to LinkedIn. But I have to upload an image URL, which is uploaded on my server.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The only difference is how you get the binary data (from the `$_FILES`-array vs loading it through `file_get_contents()`). The important part is `Content-Type`. Linked in clearly states that it should be sent as a multipart request.

Comment: I added header like this:

$curl_header=array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data", "Authorization:Bearer ".$access_token);

Now the error is                                                                                          
{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Malformed multipart request: expect only one file upload in one part","status":400}

Comment: You're sending the file wrong. Use [CurlFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) to send the file contents.

Comment: Ok let me check.

Comment: Yeah that one worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added header like this:

```
       $curl_header=array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data", 
       "Authorization:Bearer ".$access_token);
```

And changed the post params like this

```
          $curl1 = curl_init();

          $m_url="https://api.linkedin.com/media/upload";
          $uploadRequest['file'] = new CURLFile($img, 'image/png', basename($img));


            $curl_header=array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data", "Authorization:Bearer ".$access_token);

                curl_setopt_array($curl1, array(
                  CURLOPT_URL => $m_url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$uploadRequest,
                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>$curl_header,

                ));

                $response1 = curl_exec($curl1);
                $err1 = curl_error($curl1);
                $status1 = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


                curl_close($curl1);
```