# Image into string and back

Tags: php, image

I need to store images into an MSSQL database as part of a form processing which is handled by PHP.

Before that, my client did this task with following C# code:

```
  Dim content As Byte() = ImageToStream(fName)
                cnn.Open()

                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE lide SET pictPostava = @img WHERE ID = '" & GetValueToTextBox(iRow, "ID") & "'", cnn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", content)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                cnn.Close()

                content = Nothing
    Public Function ImageToStream(ByVal fileName As String) As Byte()
        Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
tryagain:
        Try
            Dim image As New Bitmap(fileName)
            image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Catch ex As Exception
            GoTo tryagain
        End Try

        Return stream.ToArray()
    End Function
```

I tried to replicate it via unpack() function based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php#31688

```
// convert file
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.sunagency.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1745083-150x150.jpg');
$unpacked = "0x" . unpack("H*hex", $file);

// get the hexcode of image
print_r( $unpacked['hex'] );
```

However, he can't restore it. And to be honest, I'm not sure how to revert it back with PHP either - changing header into Image doesn't solve the problem.

```
// view the packed file
header("Content-type: image/jpeg;");
echo $unpacked['hex'];
```

Could you help? I have never done this before and would be more than happy to solve the problem.

Comment: You might be able to store the image data using the base64_encode() and restore the image via base64_decode() see http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: Do you want to get an image file from given URL and save into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody gets the same trouble as I did, the way is to completely fake the form values:

```
    $boundary = wp_generate_password(24);
    $url = "issues/$issue_id/files.json";
    $this->content_type = "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary";

    $payload = '';
    $n = 1;
    // Upload files
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $payload .= '--' . $boundary;
        $payload .= "\r\n";
        $payload .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments['.$n.'][file]"; filename="' . basename($file) . '"' . "\r\n";
        // $payload .= 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' . "\r\n";
        // $payload .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' . "\r\n";
        $payload .= "\r\n";
        $payload .= file_get_contents($file);
        $payload .= "\r\n";
        $n++;
    }
    $payload .= '--' . $boundary . '--';
```

Here are the resources that helped me at that time (answering the question way later than I solved it), but maybe it will help someone in the future.

- https://gist.github.com/UmeshSingla/40b5f7b0fb7e0ade0438
- [Posting raw image data as multipart/form-data in curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl)