# Php curl You don't have permission to access the file when uploading image

Tags: php, curl, httpforbiddenhandler

Am trying to upload image to a server using `php curl_setopt`, but i always get `403 Forbidden` whenever i include `base64_encode($image_data)` but without that it will post successfully. I have also tried to change my `php.in`, but still yet. Everything was working fine before, till i reinstall new os in my centos server, i don't really know the cause.

**MY PHP.INI**

```
memory_limit=512M
upload_max_filesize=12M
post_max_size=128M
max_execution_time=60
max_input_vars=4000
#session.save_path=\\
session.save_path="/sessions_tmp"
magic_quotes_gpc=Off
session.gc_maxlifetime=365 * 24 * 60 * 60
session.cookie_lifetime=365 * 24 * 60 * 60
session.gc_divisor=1
session.gc_probability=1
```

MY PHP UPLOAD

```
if(($fileHandle = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "r"))){
$data = fread($fileHandle, filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$postVar  = array(
  /*This will work but using $data won't work
   'image' => base64_encode("UploadTest"),*/
  'image' => base64_encode($data), 
  'product_id' => '1020039393',
  'image_name' => 'tempCarImage.png',
  'file_name' => "CarImage",
  'upload' => 'GALLERY',
  'tag' => 1,
  'extension' => 'png',
  'chef_key' => 'M573Hakd'
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/assets/upload.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . upload_cdn_server_key));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVar);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$out = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
fclose($fileHandle);
$pms = json_decode($out,true);
}
```

Please can anyone help me, i really don't know what is causing this problem.

Comment: does your `fread()` command succeed? Does `base64_encode($data)` return a valid result? Do you have access to the source code of `https://example.com/assets/upload.php` (I realise that's not the real URL, but you get my point)? Perhaps that could tell you conditions in which it might decide to return a 403. Or perhaps the people who maintain it can tell you. Perhaps the data is too big, or something

Comment: @ADyson yes the `fread()` succeed and i have access to the file upload.php

Comment: ok then so in uploads.php is there any code where can decide to output a 403 response? If not then maybe it's happening at the webserver level. How big is the encoded data (i.e. the output of `base64_encode($data)`)?

Comment: btw, why does uploads.php not just accept a standard multi-part request instead of having to encode the file data? It's generally more efficient (as the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) notes, base64-encoding makes it 33% or so larger) and you don't have to decode it at the other side.

Comment: @ADyson please can i see an example of what you mean?

Comment: well if you fill in a HTML form to upload a file, plus other fields, you set the form's encoding type to "multipart/form-data". This tells your browser to create a muti-part request (one part for each file (binary data), and one more part containing all the other form fields (which are just text)). PHP understands this structure automatically, so when it receives that request it knows to put the regular fields in $_POST and the file data in $_FILES. If you look in your browser's network tools when you submit the form you'll see the request, and can see how the body is constructed

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you use cURL to construct the same kind of request, and then that your "uploads.php" script on the remote server is re-designed to accept data in the standard way using $_FILES and $_POST. There's a fairly decent example of the curl code here: https://gist.github.com/maxivak/18fcac476a2f4ea02e5f80b303811d5f . There'a also a very simple example of a multi-part request body at the bottom of this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Comment: Here's another demo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21927891/5947043 showing quite a similar scenario to yours - receiving uploaded files in PHP and then passing them on to another server using cURL.

Comment: Is `mod_security` enabled in Apache?  Check the Apache server error logs as this may show the request is being blocked because base64 in the post.