# How to submit multiple file images in API Laravel with using CURLOPT?

Tags: laravel, api, php-curl

I'm trying to upload multiple images in the API of Laravel but it keeps getting 500 errors.

I'm using CURLOPT PHP for the API here are the codes below.
If you have an alternative way to do this in PHP that's ok for me.

```
    $data = array(
        "images" => $request->file('input_images'),
    );

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://sample/api/name",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $result = json_decode($response);

    print_r($result);
```

Comment: You may use [Guzzle HTTP client](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). It's easy to use.

Comment: @TheAlpha could send me a sample of how it works the post files images. I appreciate it. thank you

Comment: The general idea is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl and should work with multiple files