# PHP curl submits empty payload

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use PHP curl to submit a payload with some files.  Here's my `submit.php`

```
<?php

$url = "http://example.com/receive.php";

$payload = array();
$payload['resource_name'] = 'hello world';
$payload['resource_file'] = curl_file_create("test-pdf.pdf");

$headr = array();
//$headr[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($payload));

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
print_r($response);
echo "\n";
```

And this is my `http://example.com/receive.php`

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

When I run `php submit.php` from command line I get this result:

```
Array
(
    [resource_name] => hello world
    [resource_file] => Array
        (
            [name] => test-pdf.pdf
            [mime] =>
            [postname] =>
        )

)
Array
(
)
```

Why is my `$_FILES` array empty?

If I enable the `multipart/form-data` line, then both `$_REQUEST` and `$_FILES` is empty.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I populate both the $_REQUEST and $_FILES array in receive.php?

Comment: There are lots of previous examples of this online - [see here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+curl+send+multipart+form+data+with+file). Have you tried anything from your research? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl seems to be the canonical SO answer on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `http_build_query` and problem solved.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
```

The reason is that `http_build_query` will generate URL-encoded query string for `x-www-form-urlencoded`